# Print array content when for finishes

Tags: python

I was looking to organize my torrents once they're downloaded. I wrote this script that checks for series name and seaons and moves files to other disk where I keep my tv shows.
I want some processes to be printed as they run. I'm having a problem with one of them.
I want first to print "Archivos encontrados" (which means Files founded) and then print the variable with all the files from the directory (in this case the variable is called "`series`")
The problem is that as I wrote it, it print one Archivos encontrados for each file it finds.
I've tried as you can see in line 21 to check for end of file but it doesn't work.

Also, the `else` at the end that should run if it can't find any of the extensions I've declared is not working.

Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, glob, re, os, shutil
from termcolor import colored
#enconding: utf-8

dir_series = "/home/user/series/series/"

buscar = "*[sS][0-9][0-9]*"

for serie in glob.glob(buscar):
 if serie.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv')):

  #Extraer el nombre de la serie
  nombre = re.findall(r'.*[\. ][sS]\d', serie)[0]
  nombre_final = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]\d','',nombre).replace('.',' ')

  #Extraer el número de la temporada
  season = re.findall(r'[\. ][sS]\d\d', serie)[0]
  season_final = re.sub(r'[\. ][sS]','',season)

  #if serie == serie[-1]:
  print(colored("Archivos encontrados: ",'red'))
  print(serie)


  #Armar el directorio final
  path = os.path.join(dir_series, nombre_final, ('Season '+ season_final))

  #Chequear si el directorio existe
  if not os.path.exists(path):
   print(colored("\nDirectorio no encontrado, creándolo",'cyan'))  
   os.makedirs(path) 

  #Mover el archivo
  shutil.move(serie,path)
  print(colored('\nCopiando:','green'), serie, colored('a', 'green'), path + '/' + serie)


 else:
  print('No hay archivos para organizar.\n')

input("\n\nPresione Enter para continuar ...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if serie == serie[-1]` check doesn't work because instead of checking "if the series is the last one in the list", you check "if the series is also the last character of the same series".

Consider using something like this instead:

```
series = [s for s in glob.glob(buscar) if s.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv'))]
if series:
    print(colored("Archivos encontrados: ",'red'))
    for serie in series:
        print(serie)
        ...
else:
    print('No hay archivos para organizar.\n')
```

Comment: Hi! I did a modification to your suggestion and now it's working! thanks!


`series = [s for s in glob.glob(buscar) if s.endswith(('.mp4', '.srt', '.avi', '.mkv'))]
if series:
    print(colored("\nArchivos encontrados: ",'red'))
    print(*series, sep = "\n")
    for serie in series:`